# pipeline and cross validation in python using scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, cross-validation, polynomials

I had a general doubt for Cross Validation.

In the notebook for module 2 it is mentioned that one should use pipelines for Cross Validation in order to prevent data leakage. I understand why , however had a doubt regarding the pipeline function:

If I want to use three functions in a pipeline : `MinMaxScaler()`, `PolynomialFeatures`(for multiple degrees) and A `Ridge` in the end(for multiple alpha values). Since I want to find the best model after using multiple param values , I will use the `GridSearchCV()` function which does cross validation and gives the best model score.

However after I intialise a pipeline object with the three functions and insert it in the `GridSearchCV()` function , how do I insert the multiple degrees and aplha values in the `params` parameter of the `GridSearchCV()` function . Do I insert the params as a list of two lists in the order of which the functions have been defined in the pipeline object or do I send a dictionary of two lists, where the keys are the object names of the functions in the pipeline ?????

Comment: Could you add your code to this question? It would make it much easier to understand what you're having trouble with

Answer (score 1):

You just have to feed it as a dictionary.

Try this example:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

X, y = make_regression(random_state=42)

pipe = make_pipeline(MinMaxScaler(), PolynomialFeatures(),  Ridge())

pipe
# Pipeline(steps=[('minmaxscaler', MinMaxScaler()),
#                 ('polynomialfeatures', PolynomialFeatures()),
#                 ('ridge', Ridge())])

gs = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid={'polynomialfeatures__degree': [2,4],
                                    'ridge__alpha': [1,10]}).fit(X, y)

# gs.best_params_
# {'polynomialfeatures__degree': 2, 'ridge__alpha': 1}
```